# tf shifted step function based on a learnt variable

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build a shifted reversed step function based on a learn variable:
e.g

```
step_length = 8
learn_point = tf.Variable(step_length/2) #initial value
step = tf.Variable(np.ones(step_length),dtype=tf.float32,trainable=False)
step = tf.scatter_update(step,tf.range(learn_point,step_length),tf.zeros(tf.reshape(learn_point,[1])))

    #will generate 
    # step = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0] -> for learn_point = 4
    # step = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0] -> for learn_point = 5
```

I tried achieving this using the code above, but because scatter update doesn't have gradient specified returned the error

```
LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'ScatterUpdate_4' (op type: ScatterUpdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different method, as most of the sparse functions yet doesn't have a gradiend defined for operation.

```
    step = tf.concat([tf.ones(given_axis - weight_param,dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.zeros(weight_param,dtype=tf.float32)],axis=-1)
```

achieves the same functionality